# Azure Data factory issue Bool expression

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

```
{
    "name": "pipeline2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Until1",
                "type": "Until",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@bool()(variables('Fileavilable '))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Get Metadata1",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "Source",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "exists"
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "BinaryReadSettings"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "If Condition1",
                            "type": "IfCondition",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Completed"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "expression": {
                                    "value": "bool()(@activity('Get Metadata1').output.exists)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "ifFalseActivities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Wait1",
                                        "type": "Wait",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "waitTimeInSeconds": 120
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "ifTrueActivities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Set variable1",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "Fileavilable ",
                                            "value": "True"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Until1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Completed"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "BinarySource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "BinaryReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "BinarySink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "Source",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "Sink",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "Fileavilable ": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "false"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

I am trying to copy files from one Blob storage to another. But these files depend on third-party applications. So whenever files generated, event trigger will occur. So I have used Until activity. I am facing issue while converting the string into bool expression. I am getting error ,'function bool doesn't accept the  0 arguments'. Please advice me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, when I tried your expression to a boolean type variable.

[image]

Here, in [`bool()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#bool) function, you didn't passed any value and that is the reason for this error. If you pass `0` in it, it will give `false` and for `1`, it will give `true`.

Make the below changes in your pipeline, to achieve your requirement.

- You have created variable `Fileavilable` as a string type and given value `"false"` in its default value. Change that to `boolean` type.

  [image]

  **Before the Until activity, use a Set variable activity** and set the `false` boolean value to the above variable using the below expression `@bool(0)`.

  [image]

  Now, you can directly use this variable in the until activity expression and there is no need to use `bool()` function in it.
- Inside until, again you didn't gave any value inside `bool()` for the `if` expression. **The value of `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.exists` is itself a boolean (`true`/`false`)**. So no need to use any function in it. Give this `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.exists` expression directly in the if expression.
- Inside the **if True activities**, you are setting the `"True"` string value to the `Fileavilable`. As we changed the variable's type to boolean, use `@bool(1)` to set the `true` boolean value to it.